# Is there a way to measure image load time other than the Resource Timing API?

Tags: javascript, performance, analytics, metrics

The [Resource Timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) provides reporting on how long individual images on a page take to load. For example, loading this simplified demo in Chrome will report how long it takes the image to load.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<title>Image Timing Test</title>
<script>
  function determineImageTiming(url) {
    var reportDiv = document.getElementById('report');
    if (window.performance.getEntriesByName) {
      var timer = window.performance.getEntriesByName(url);
      var imageLoadTime = timer[0]['responseEnd'].toFixed(0);      
      reportDiv.innerHTML = 'Image Loaded at: ' + imageLoadTime + 'ms';
    }
    else {
      reportDiv.innerHTML = "window.performance.getEntriesByName not available";
    }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="determineImageTiming('http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract')">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/abstract">
  <div id="report">Measuring...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

([This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alanwsmith/n9rwvg8a/) shows it in action in browsers like Chrome that support the functionality.)

Is there a way to mimic this behavior, even if it's less accurate, to determine how long a specific image takes to load on a page in browsers that don't support `window.performance`?

Comment: very late comment, you should consider using the onload callback on the image and console.time and console.timeEnd can provide the loading information as well